# Usage of "can't help it"

Tags: expressions

I am wondering how can we use "can't help it" in a sentence.
I want you to explain me it's grammer  definition and I would appreciate if you could provide some examples of this expression for me

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=%22can%27t+help+it%22+meaning . Top result.

Answer (score 1):

"**can't help it**" is, as a phrase, roughly synonymous with "**unable to prevent it from happening/being the case**" where "it" is an action or habit previously or about to be mentioned.

Here are some examples of its use:

> ***I can't help it if you don't have enough money!*** (I am unable to prevent the situation where you have insufficient funds for your purchase)
>
> ***Biting strangers isn't his fault; he can't help it.*** (He is unable to prevent his compulsion to sink his teeth into people he doesn't know)

Alternatively, click Max Williams' link.

Answer (score 1):

This specific sense of ***help*** usage is defined by OED as...

> **help** 11a: *To remedy, obviate, prevent, cause to be otherwise*.
>    (With **can, cannot**, or some equivalent.)

It goes back a long way - two of OED's early citations are...

> [Francis Bacon, 1605](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=OKRSAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT136&dq=deficience%20cannot%20bee%20holpen&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=deficience%20cannot%20bee%20holpen&f=false) *- ...the deficience cannot be holpen* (the deficiency can't be helped)
>    [William Shakespeare, 1616](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LwFEAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA38&dq=lament%20for%20that%20thou%20canst%20not&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=lament%20for%20that%20thou%20canst%20not&f=false) *- Cease to lament for that thou canst not help*

Note that this usage *always* requires a ***negatory*** context. It's perfectly normal to say *I **can't** help [**it**, or "doing something"]* to mean *I'm unable to stop [doing] it*, but no-one ever says *I **can** help it* to mean they *are* able to prevent something happening.

---

Common usages today include...

> *He can't help it* ("it" is usually something undesirable that he can't stop doing)
>    *It can't be helped* ("it" is some undesirable situation that cannot be avoided)
>    *He couldn't help laughing* (his undesirable action expressed using the continuous verb form)

Comment: You're not going to get away with that last paragraph if I can help it.

Comment: @John: I can't help it if you don't recognize *You're **not** going to get away with that* as a "negatory" context! :)

Comment: I can totally help it.

Comment: Given enough context, we can both totally say what we like without people thinking we must be non-native speakers. (But they might still think we're totally illiterate! :)

Comment: Do you also use "You can't help it!"?

Comment: @Lifeispicnic: There less contexts where I  would actually say ***You** can't help it* (so whatever inappropriate thing you're doing, *it's not really your "fault"*, because you can't stop yourself from doing it), but it's perfectly valid English. I only explicitly specified ***He** can't help it* as an ***example***. The basic construction works with any pronoun / proper name *(**I, You, He, She, We, They, Bob, Alice,...**)*. Don't take too much notice of the banter between me and John several years ago. His ***I can totally help it*** is contextually-licensed "wordplay" (not normal English).